# sed: delete n lines after first match

Tags: sed

I want to delete *N* number of lines after the first match in a text file using sed.

(I know most of these questions have been answered with "**use awk**", but I want to use sed, regardless of how much more powerful it is than awk. It's more a matter of which tool I'm most comfortable with using at the moment, within a certain time constraint)

The furthest I got is this:

```
sed -i "0,/pattern/{/pattern/,+Nd}" file.txt
```

The thought is that *0,* denotes the first occurrence, where the curly brackets search the first line for the pattern, and deletes *N* lines after that occurence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
sed '/pattern/{N;N;N;N;N;N;N;d;}' file.txt
```

The `0,` construct and the relative line number addressing you tried to use are specific to GNU `sed`. Portable `sed` does not have these facilities.

This will remove the next six lines after *every* match. If you only want to remove the first occurrence and leave the rest of the file unchanged, maybe add a separate loop to simply print all remaining lines.

The problem with your attempt is that `0,/pattern/` restricts matching to the lines up through the first occurrence of `/pattern/` but then that's the end of the range, so anything selected by this expression cannot operate on lines outside of that range.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your shell is `bash` (the question originally had a `bash` tag):

```
n=3
sed -f <(printf -v nsp '%*s' $n; printf '/%s/{x;/./!{s/^/./;h;%sd;};x;}\n' 'pattern' "${nsp// /N;}") file
```

Note that `n` is variable (`3` is just an instance) and constructed `sed` script is not GNU specific.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '0,/pattern/{//{:a;N;s/\n/&/N;Ta;d}}' file
```

Deletes the line containing `pattern` and then `N` lines after it once only.

Alternative:

```
sed '/pattern/{x;//{x;b};x;h;:a;N;s/\n/&/N;Ta;d}' file
```

N.B. The `N` following the substitution command refers to the nth occurrence of a newline in the pattern space.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE 1 : Example where sed solution above does not meet objective universally:

```
cmd='/5=P$/{N;N;N;N;N;N;d;}'
echo "\n input \${b} :: \n\n———————\n" \
     "${b}\n--------------\n\n sed "    \
     "commands :: \n\n--------------\n " \
     "${cmd}\n--------------\n\n GNU sed "\
     "::\n\n$( gsed "${cmd}" <<< "${b}" )" \
     "\n\n BSD sed ::\n\n$( sed "${cmd}" <<< "${b}" )\n\n"

 input ${b} :: 

--------------
    84  77138=48001=P
    85  77138=48035=P
    86  77138=78118=P
    87  77138=79248=P
--------------

 sed commands :: 

--------------
 /5=P$/{N;N;N;N;N;N;d;}
--------------

 GNU sed ::

    84  77138=48001=P
    85  77138=48035=P
    86  77138=78118=P
    87  77138=79248=P

 BSD sed ::

    84  77138=48001=P
```

For unknown reasons, when the input lacks sufficient rows past the pattern,

- this solution works on `BSD sed`,
- but totally fails on `GNU sed`.

============================

Is `sed` a must have requirement ? You can also do one-liners with `awk` :

(it's intentionally verbose to showcase exactly what the lines matched and skipped look like) :

```
# gawk profile, created Thu Apr 28 18:36:55 2022

# BEGIN rule(s)

BEGIN {
 1      printf "\n\t N :: %.f :: FS i.e. "\
               "pattern :: %*s\n\n", N = +N, ++__, FS = pattern
}

# Rule(s)

87  NF *= -(_+=(_= __<NF ? -__-N :_)^!__)<+_ { # 45
45      print
}


     1  77138=501=A
     2  77138=3413=A
     3  77138=3414=A
     4  77138=8624=A
     5  77138=19572=A
     6  77138=22220=A
     7  77138=23670=A
     8  77138=25413=A
     9  77138=26351=A
    10  77138=27340=A
    11  77138=29288=A
    12  77138=121060=A
    13  77138=123028=A
    14  77138=132081=A
    15  77138=135789=A
    16  77138=154341=A
    17  77138=155876=A
    18  77138=170871=A
    19  77138=178562=A
skipped ::     20   77138=185367=A
skipped ::     21   77138=196718=A
skipped ::     22   77138=196985=A
skipped ::     23   77138=200012=A
skipped ::     24   77138=207162=A
skipped ::     25   77138=228289=A
skipped ::     26   77138=244747=A
skipped ::     27   77138=284795=A
skipped ::     28   77138=294579=A
skipped ::     29   77138=299765=A
skipped ::     30   77138=317856=A
skipped ::     31   77138=318815=A
    32  77138=324570=A
    33  77138=408049=A
    34  77138=514403=A
    35  77138=1647865=A
    36  77138=1738771=A
    37  77138=3217183=A
skipped ::     38   77138=3222837=A
skipped ::     39   77138=3235292=A
skipped ::     40   77138=14957980=I
skipped ::     41   77138=1159=M
skipped ::     42   77138=1196=M
skipped ::     43   77138=1251=M
    44  77138=1252=M
    45  77138=4951=M
    46  77138=16740=M
    47  77138=71501=M
skipped ::     48   77138=137=P
skipped ::     49   77138=348=P
skipped ::     50   77138=518=P
skipped ::     51   77138=519=P
skipped ::     52   77138=520=P
skipped ::     53   77138=925=P
    54  77138=1363=P
    55  77138=1483=P
    56  77138=1814=P
    57  77138=2692=P
    58  77138=3540=P
    59  77138=3594=P
    60  77138=3682=P
    61  77138=3869=P
    62  77138=3940=P
skipped ::     63   77138=3977=P
skipped ::     64   77138=4025=P
skipped ::     65   77138=4252=P
skipped ::     66   77138=4396=P
skipped ::     67   77138=9501=P
skipped ::     68   77138=13006=P
    69  77138=18113=P
skipped ::     70   77138=20907=P
skipped ::     71   77138=31936=P
skipped ::     72   77138=34954=P
skipped ::     73   77138=37126=P
skipped ::     74   77138=37482=P
skipped ::     75   77138=40135=P
    76  77138=40206=P
    77  77138=41279=P
    78  77138=41280=P
    79  77138=46140=P
skipped ::     80   77138=46157=P
skipped ::     81   77138=46173=P
skipped ::     82   77138=46218=P
skipped ::     83   77138=47592=P
skipped ::     84   77138=48001=P
skipped ::     85   77138=48035=P
    86  77138=78118=P
    87  77138=79248=P
 

     N :: 5 :: FS i.e. pattern :: [7]=[AP]$

     1  77138=501=A
     2  77138=3413=A
     3  77138=3414=A
     4  77138=8624=A
     5  77138=19572=A
     6  77138=22220=A
     7  77138=23670=A
     8  77138=25413=A
     9  77138=26351=A
    10  77138=27340=A
    11  77138=29288=A
    12  77138=121060=A
    13  77138=123028=A
    14  77138=132081=A
    15  77138=135789=A
    16  77138=154341=A
    17  77138=155876=A
    18  77138=170871=A
    19  77138=178562=A
    32  77138=324570=A
    33  77138=408049=A
    34  77138=514403=A
    35  77138=1647865=A
    36  77138=1738771=A
    37  77138=3217183=A
    44  77138=1252=M
    45  77138=4951=M
    46  77138=16740=M
    47  77138=71501=M
    54  77138=1363=P
    55  77138=1483=P
    56  77138=1814=P
    57  77138=2692=P
    58  77138=3540=P
    59  77138=3594=P
    60  77138=3682=P
    61  77138=3869=P
    62  77138=3940=P
    69  77138=18113=P
    76  77138=40206=P
    77  77138=41279=P
    78  77138=41280=P
    79  77138=46140=P
    86  77138=78118=P
    87  77138=79248=P
```

more concisely, it would be

```
mawk -v pattern='[7]=[AP]$' -v N='5' -- '
BEGIN { 
      ++__ 
   FS = pattern 
} NF *= -(_+=(_=__<NF?-__-N:_)^!__) < +_'
```

or in `awk` `one-liner style`

```
mawk 'NF*=-(_+=(_=1<NF?-1-N:_)^0)<+_' FS='[7]=[AP]$' N=5
```

Comment: Seriously, the question mentions that they know how to do this in Awk but want a `sed` solution.

Comment: yeah , and i don't see how offering a inflexible solution that require self-repeating such as "sed '/pattern/{N;N;N;N;N;N;N;d;}'" is helpful at all to OP. At least the solution I offered allows user to pick any pattern that don't need back-references and any value of N, and could even be made into a shell function. Furthermore, please see my updated comment where I list an example that sed-based solution completely fails.