# sed print N lines after match

Tags: sed, gnu

I have a file containing these lines:

```
some junk
in here

log number 1
line1, data, here
line2,data,here
line3,data,here
and so on

some other
junk

log number 2
line one, some,data
line two, some,data
line three, blablabla
```

I want to match and print about hundred lines after *n-th* match of `log number ...` lines.
[this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72047036/9439683) works, but I don't want to type a 100 Ns in my sed command.

Also `/log.*\n(.*\n){2}/gm` (printing 2 lines after match) works on [regex101](https://regex101.com/) but not on my terminal (sed doesn't match `\n`).

I use arch linux and GNU sed version 4.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does something like this not work?

```
$ sed -n '/log.*1/,+4p' file
log number 1
line1, data, here
line2,data,here
line3,data,here
and so on
```

If you just need to print 100 lines after the match, it should be all you need.

```
$ sed -n '/log.*1/,+100p' file
```

Comment: Is there a way to eliminate the number in `/log.*1/` and choose which instance of match to be printed? e.g if I have 3 `log number n` lines in my file (n is random number) , I could choose the match (1st, 2nd or 3rd) to be printed.